# Django - mongoengine - Circular imports in models files of different apps

Tags: django, django-models, mongoengine, circular-dependency

I have 2 Apps, user and boxes. Their models contain 2 classes each and none of the classes have circular dependency but model file have circular dependency.

Their models are as below

```
#users/models.py

from mongoengine import fields, Document
from boxes.models import *

class Token(Document):
    id = fields.IntField(primary_key=True)
    key = fields.StringField(required=True)
    box = fields.ReferenceField(Box)

class User(Document):
    id = fields.IntField(primary_key=True)
    name = fields.StringField(required=True)


#boxes/models.py

from mongoengine import fields, Document
from users.models import *

class Box(Document):
    id = fields.IntField(primary_key=True)
    name = fields.StringField(required=True)


class Testing(Document):
    id = fields.IntField(primary_key=True)
    field1 = fields.StringField(required=True)
    field_ref = fields.ReferenceField(User)
```

I am getting below error in Testing Class during starting the server

```
NameError: name 'User' is not defined
```

Things I tried :

```
#Trial 1
from django.apps import apps

field_ref = fields.ReferenceField(apps.get_model('users', 'User'))
#error
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Models are not loaded yet.


#Trial 2
field_ref = fields.ReferenceField('User')
OR
field_ref = fields.ReferenceField('users.User')
#Error
mongoengine.errors.ValidationError: ValidationError (Box:5b8ddef7a095d8586d2263bb) (A ReferenceField only accepts DBRef or documents: ['user'])
```

I tried solutions given in other posts as well but the are not working.

I am using Django =1.9. Any help will be really appreciated.

Comment: In user/models change from boxes.models import * to from boxes.models import Box

Comment: @Trent, I tried that, same error

Answer (score 1):

Old question but it may be helpful to others. Your main problem should be in these lines:

```
#users/models.py
from boxes.models import *
...
#boxes/models.py
from users.models import *
```

You are trying to import each model to other. Just try to read this like interpreter does. That's a cycle. **Do not import models each one to other.** Because if you do then sooner or later you will get circular imports. Instead of this do:

```
#models/__init__.py

# Use explicit imports, not *
from boxes.models import Box, Testing
from users.models import Token, User

#users/models.py

from mongoengine import fields, Document
# from boxes.models import * <-- remove this line

class Token(Document):
    ...
    box = fields.ReferenceField('Box')  # model name in quotes

class User(Document):
    ...

#boxes/models.py

from mongoengine import fields, Document
# from users.models import * <-- remove this line

class Box(Document):
    ...


class Testing(Document):
    ...
    field_ref = fields.ReferenceField('User')  # model name in quotes
```

And I said "Do not import models one to other". I mean it. If you want to use another model in current model method do not import model. Try this:

```
from mongoengine.base import get_document as get_model
...
User = get_model('User')
```

Actually this is the function that uses for getting model when you code like this: `fields.ReferenceField('User')`